# Postgresql trigger IF condition to see if destination table has this record

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a straight forward trigger function that is set to run on UPDATE or INSERT in a table.

When this trigger runs, I want to insert the record into another table, only if it doesn't already exist there.

I could simply ignore checking and let the insert fail, but I feel like that's not the best approach.

```
-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER archivelogic_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON entsf.et4ae5__individualemailresult__c
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE entsf.archivelogicfunc();


-- Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION entsf.archivelogicfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $result_table$
   BEGIN       
BEGIN
        IF (DATE(NEW.et4ae5__datesent__c) < NOW() - INTERVAL '180 days' 
        AND DATE(NEW.et4ae5__datesent__c) > NOW() - INTERVAL '540 days'
        AND NEW.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM archive.individualemailresult__c)) -- this seems expensive
        THEN
          INSERT INTO archive.individualemailresult__c 
                (dateopened__c, 
                 numberoftotalclicks__c, 
                 datebounced__c, 
                 fromname__c, 
                 hardbounce__c, 
                 fromaddress__c, 
                 softbounce__c, 
                 name, 
                 lastmodifieddate, 
                 opened__c, 
                 ownerid, 
                 subjectline__c, 
                 isdeleted, 
                 contact__c, 
                 systemmodstamp, 
                 lastmodifiedbyid, 
                 datesent__c, 
                 dateunsubscribed__c, 
                 createddate, 
                 createdbyid, 
                 lead__c, 
                 tracking_as_of__c, 
                 numberofuniqueclicks__c, 
                 senddefinition__c, 
                 mergeid__c, 
                 triggeredsenddefinition__c, 
                 sfid, 
                 id, 
                 _hc_lastop, 
                 _hc_err)
            VALUES 
                (NEW.et4ae5__dateopened__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__numberoftotalclicks__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__datebounced__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__fromname__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__hardbounce__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__fromaddress__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__softbounce__c, 
                NEW.name, 
                NEW.lastmodifieddate, 
                NEW.et4ae5__opened__c, 
                NEW.ownerid, 
                NEW.et4ae5__subjectline__c, 
                NEW.isdeleted, 
                NEW.et4ae5__contact__c, 
                NEW.systemmodstamp, 
                NEW.lastmodifiedbyid, 
                NEW.et4ae5__datesent__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__dateunsubscribed__c, 
                NEW.createddate, 
                NEW.createdbyid, 
                NEW.et4ae5__lead__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__tracking_as_of__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__numberofuniqueclicks__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__senddefinition__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__mergeid__c, 
                NEW.et4ae5__triggeredsenddefinition__c, 
                NEW.sfid, 
                NEW.id, 
                NEW._hc_lastop, 
                NEW._hc_err);
            END IF;
            RETURN NULL;
       END;
```

I added the line in my logic that checks to see if that ID exists in the other table, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it?

`AND NEW.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM archive.individualemailresult__c)) -- this seems expensive`

Comment: Create a unique constraint and use `on conflict do nothing`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can it be the primary key? `ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO NOTHING;` for example?

Comment: Yes of course the primary key is unique by definition